# Partitions of Unity-Integration on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

So lets say I have a $k$-manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I cover it up with coordinate patches $\{\alpha_i\}$. I can find a set of partitions of unity $\{\phi_1,...\phi_l\}$ on $M$ which is dominated by the coordinate patches (that is each of their supports has to be a subset of a coordinate patch). Now lets say I map $M$ via an isometry $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ to $N$, s.t. $h(M)=N$. I know that N would then be covered by the coordinate patches $h\circ\alpha_i$ (So $N$ is in fact a k-manifold trivially). Now I have been told that it follows that the partitions of unity on $N$ would be of the form $\{\phi_1\circ h^{-1},...\phi_l\circ h^{-1}\}$. Can someone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every point $x \in N$, we claim that $$\sum (\phi_i \circ h^{-1})(x) = 1$$

But since $h$ is an isometry, it's bijective, so $h^{-1}(x)$ is a point in $M$; and $$\sum (\phi_i \circ h^{-1})(x) = \sum \phi_i(h^{-1}(x)) = 1$$ since $\{\phi_i\}$ is a partition of unity on $M$. In addition, since $\text{supp } \phi_i \subset \alpha_i, \text{supp }\phi_i \circ h^{-1} \subset h(\alpha_i)$.

So $\{\phi_i \circ h^{-1}\}$ is a partition of unity subordinate to $\{h(\alpha_i)\}$.